# Javascript alert not working during form validation

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what is the mistake but I can't get the alert when I press the button without selecting the checkboxes. Can someone let me know what mistake am I making here.

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validator(form) {
                if (form.q36.value.length == 0) {
                    alert("Select one environment");
                    form.q36.setfocus();
                    return (false);
                }
                if (form.q56.value.length == 0) {
                    alert("Select one environment");
                    form.q56.setfocus();
                    return (false);
                }
                if (form.q77.value.length == 0) {
                    alert("Select one environment");
                    form.q77.setfocus();
                    return (false);
                }

                if (form.apppath.value.length == 0) {
                    alert("Enter the path");
                    form.apppath.setfocus();
                    return (false);
                }
                return (true);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="/car.java" onsubmit="return validator(this);">
            <br />
            <p>One
                <input name="q36" id="q36" type="checkbox" />Two
                <input name="q56" id="q56" type="checkbox" />Three
                <input name="q77" id="q77" type="checkbox" />
            </p>
            <br />
            <input name="apppath" size="123" style="width: 766px; height: 21px;" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input name="uipath" size="123" style="width: 766px; height: 21px;" type="text" />
            </p>
            <textarea cols="95" name="status" rows="11"></textarea>
            <input name="sub" size="28" style="width: 156px; height: 29px;" type="button" value="Deploy" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your button to type='submit' instead of type='button'

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your value is undefinied so the length function doesnt execute. You can try to step through it with firebug or make a fiddle.

You can also try adding a value on the input checkboxes.